# The strange \luaescapestring in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex

```
\directlua{%
  local s = [[\luaescapestring{\TeX}]]
  print(s)}
```

After `\luaescapestring{\TeX}`, I think I should get

```
T\\kern -.1667em\\lower .5ex\\hbox {E}\\kern -.125emX
```

then this line will be converted into a string in Lua by using `[[ ]]` operation(at the same time, `\\` will be `\`), thus,

```
s = "T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX"
```

but the result printed is

```
T\\kern -.1667em\\lower .5ex\\hbox {E}\\kern -.125emX
```

why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

compare the different output:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\directlua{tex.enableprimitives("",tex.extraprimitives())}
\begin{document}

\directlua{%
  local s = [[\luaescapestring{\TeX}]]
  print(s)}

\directlua{%
  local s = "\luaescapestring{\TeX}"
  print(s)}

\end{document}


T\\kern -.1667em\\lower .5ex\\hbox {E}\\kern -.125emX\\spacefactor \\@m 
T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\spacefactor \@m
```

With `[[ ... ]]` the backslash has no meaning and is escaped

Answer (score 9):

This is because `[[...]]` is a "safe" string, which is not what `\luaescapestring` is made for. This adds two backslashes to a string instead of one.

This is with regular Lua and is nothing special with LuaTeX:

```
a = [[foo \\ bar]]
print(a)

b = "foo \\ bar"
print(b)
```

prints

```
foo \\ bar
foo \ bar
```

`\luaescapestring{}` replaces each backslash with two backslashes, regardless of the type of string you are defining (double bracket or double quote), because it doesn't know about it. That way you get two backslashes instead of one in the first string.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am too careless when reading the programming in Lua.

Comment: @TimothyLi I always skip these details when leaning something, because I don't understand its implications. Only when I stumble upon issues like the one you mention, I re-read the documentation.